# Set up ad-hoc FTP server?

Tags: ftp

A client wants to send me a very large file (3+ GB), but I'm kind of at a loss on how to receive it. My Dropbox is full, and I don't have any other kind of file sharing service. Sites like WeTransfer.com have a file size limit.

So, I looked into using Homebrew to install vsftpd or proftpd, but they're not that straightforward to set up. I really just want a simple FTP server I can launch, make up a username and password, and have my client FTP in to upload the file directly to my Mac.

I need something that will let me specify a different port number other than the standard FTP port.

How can I do this?

I'm using Mac OS 10.9.5, BTW.

Comment: What about File sharing in sys pref Sharing ?

Comment: That appears to be AFP/SMB only. I need FTP.

Comment: Did you try using the build in FTP "    sudo -s launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist  "

Comment: Doesn't Google Drive offer 5Gb. for free?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I need something that will let me specify a different port number other than the standard FTP port.

Comment: that is done by " -P dataport" see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/ftpd.8.html for more details

Comment: I don't see how to pass the `-P <port>` argument to the `launchctl` command above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install [OS X Server](https://www.apple.com/osx/server/specs/). Then you will be able to start a ftp server in few clicks.

Comment: Won't work, I'm on Mavericks.

Comment: Then you need OS X Server version 3.

Comment: Can you show me somewhere that OS X Server has an FTP server? I don't see it mentioned, just SMB, AFP, and WebDAV.

Comment: Check this [image](http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Screen-Shot-2013-10-31-at-5.21.06-PM.png) and you will see FTP under advanced. You can see it on  [this article](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/12/a-power-users-guide-to-os-x-server-mavericks-edition/).

Comment: I think you are talking about sharing option on system preferences and I'm talking about OS X Server, which is different.

Comment: Awesome! Looks like you have OS X Server, can you check if the FTP section lets you change the default port number?

Comment: From the OS X Server help: Change the FTP share point
By default, FTP service is enabled for the site root folder of the first website you’re managing with Websites service. You can designate another folder if you prefer.

The folder you designate applies only to FTP service and not to other File Sharing protocols (AFP, SMB, and WebDAV).

In the FTP pane of the Server app, choose Custom from the Share pop-up menu.

Navigate to where you want the FTP-only file share, then select an existing folder or click the New Folder button to define your share point.

Click Choose.

Comment: Is it possible to change the FTP port number?

Comment: No, you can't do it.